# How do I create a download link knowing the uploaded file ID?

Tags: 7

I've a column in database containing the IDs of the files uploaded using a *managed file* form field.

How do I create a link to the uploaded file knowing its file ID?

EDIT : 
The obvious solution doesn't work for me , i'm using another table where i put my Fids .

this is the warning i got everytime :
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in Affichage_form() (line 188 of C:\wamp64\www\Gestion_tickets_licences\sites\all\modules\Recherche\Recherche.module). << 188 : $uri= $file->uri; >>

Solution : Thank you for you help .
my solution for my problem is , Once I upload the file , I create the url. Instead of saving Fid , I save the url , It worked .For the download link , I used Alen syntax and it worked great .

Comment: just display it as a generic file (display settings in node or in view)

Comment: Can you explain more i'm new with drupal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can load file with id with [file_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_load/7.x) function and then you need to write `<a href='file_path' download > file_name </a>`

Comment: thank you  but it didn't work for me , does the fid need to be registered in the fale_managed table ? because in my case  I have a different table where I put fids of my uploaded files .

Comment: Yes, use Drupal's built-in file management system, it'll make your life a lot easier in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

First, load the file using file_load(FILE_ID) and get URI like below:

```
$file = file_load(1);
$uri = $file->uri;
```

After that generate link using file_create_url();

```
$url = file_create_url($uri);
```

Get file name also:

```
$filename  = $file->filename;
```

And finally, create a link using [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7.x).

```
l(t($filename), $url);
```

and output will be like `<a href="http://d7.local/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-6.png">picture-6.png</a>`

Comment: I did this before but somehow the $uri is always  empty , Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in Affichage_form() (line 188 ) which is $uri = $file->uri;

Comment: Can you update your question with code you have tried?